# PHP, Requesting from link and echoing json array

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, post

I have this code but it does not seem to be working. After entering an IP into the text field and hitting the button it will return with the page loaded up to the php code but will not load the php code result nor any code past it.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['resolve'])){
    $api = "https://iphub.p.mashape.com/api.php?ip=";

    $endbit = "&showtype=4";
    if(strlen($_POST['name'])==0){
        echo "fill in all fields!";
    } else {
        // assuming $_POST['resolve'] has an IP

      //  $response = file_get_contents($api.$_POST['name'].$endbit); 

      $response = Unirest\Request::get($api.$_POST['name'].$endbit,
array(
"X-Mashape-Key" => "U3sk6nAZzBmshyiHEUZHigxLGp1ZTZnKjsnkd8LWULJmRRp",
"Accept" => "application/json"
  )
);



        ?>

        <div align="center">

        <?php 
        if($response['proxy'] == '0') {
            echo 'No';
        }
        elseif($response['proxy'] == '1') {
            echo 'Yes';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error.';
        }
        ?>

        </div>

        <?php
     }
}
?>
```

The API I am using requires me to have the header/X-Mashape-Key.

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on? Perhaps a fatal error loading your `Unirest` class(es)?

Comment: How do I put error_reporting(E_ALL); on?

Comment: Is this code at the very top of your page?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter since you say it gets to this point and fails. After `<?php ` write `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); `

Comment: I get this error:
`Fatal error: Class 'Unirest\Request' not found in /var/www/html/proxy.php on line 254`